# Select element always opens upward in IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, html-select, dropdown

I have a standard `<select>` element on a page and it always opens upwards in IE 11 and Edge. There is plenty of space below, but it always opens up.

**EDIT:** The last item is pre-selected, yet it opens downwards on Chrome and Firefox. I would like to work this way in IE too.

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: Because the bottom one is pre-selected?

Comment: Yes, it is pre-selected, still it opens downwards in Chrome and Firefox. 
Can I make it behave like that in IE too?

Comment: No. Because IE has to be different. Because the designers of IE know that as soon as it plays the same as other browsers, developers will get board and be sad :(

Comment: On a more serious note what it is, is the Edge Engine doesn't move the selected element outside of the input box, I think this is a coverall for mobile devices, but if you pre-select a middle choice that will also not appear to move when the dropdown box is selected.

Comment: Behaves same on both Edge and IE 11

Comment: @VeselinVasilev - yeah, it's the native windows 10 dropdown for both IE11 and Edge. All drop downs in Windows 10 apps operate the same way. You would need a dropdown replacement of some kind.

Comment: @misterManSam do you have any url that says this is the default behavior in Win 10?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev - Not sure, I'm sure it is mentioned somewhere. My only source is that I am using Windows 10 and the dropdown in Windows apps has the same behaviour as the dropdowns IE 11 and edge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the select to open downward, one trick is to set the selection to 0 on click.

```js
document.getElementById('theSelect').onmousedown = (function() {
 this.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

```html
<select id="theSelect">
 <option value="1">one</option>
 <option value="2">two</option>
 <option value="3" selected="selected">three</option>
</select>
```

OK, a lousy trick I admit, but at least it can be done!